# Laravel 5.2 Routes

Tags: php, laravel

how it is done to declare a route? such as "site.domain / X / {id} / Y" ... because in my routes I have something similar

```
Route :: get ( '/X', function () {
   $Var = Var::all();
   return view ('pages.view') -> withVars ($var);
});
```

but it is only in the path "/X" I need access to another site after id as I said in the example

> site.domain /X/{id}/Y

Comment: Have you done any reading on the laravel route model binding or implicit binding? You can check what your routes will work for using `php artisan route:list` as well to help you with routes. Refer to the docs and come back if you have a specific error you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily doing it with another route:

```
Route::get( '/X{id}/Y', function ($id) {
   // do something
   return view ('pages.view') -> withVars ($var);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fixed

```
Route::get('ph/{id}/informe', function ($id) {
      $ph = Ph::find($id);
      return view('ph.informe')->withphs($ph);
    });
```